# Django : redirect still remains in the same page

Tags: python, django, redirect

After successful login I redirect the page to another app called  "feeds". But the url changed accordingly but the content still showing the same login page.

views.py

```
def jlogin(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST['uname']
    password = request.POST['pword']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request,user)
        print(user)
        return redirect('/feeds/')
    else:
        return render(request,'join/register.html')
else:
  return render(request,'join/login.html')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^j$',join_views.register, name='register'),
    url(r'',join_views.jlogin, name='login'),

    ]
```

main urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'',include('join.urls',namespace='join')),
    url(r'feeds',include('feeds.urls',namespace='feeds')),
    url(r'^discussion/', include('discussion.urls',namespace='discussion')),

    ]
```

If i use like this it loaded the "feeds"app content

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^login/',include('join.urls',namespace='join')),
    url(r'',include('feeds.urls',namespace='feeds')),
    url(r'^discussion/', include('discussion.urls',namespace='discussion')),

    ]
```

Why these happening ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of these two lines from

**urls.py**

```
url(r'',include('join.urls',namespace='join')),
```

and **join/urls.py**

```
url(r'',join_views.jlogin, name='login'),
```

Two **empty** regexes catch all urls.  Try any other url, for example "/shmeeds/", and you will see the same page again :-)

To solve this problem add any non-empty regex to one (or both) of these `url()`.

Comment: oh thanks .. changing url(r'',include('join.urls',namespace='join')), to url(r'^$',include('join.urls',namespace='join')), this redirects correctly.

Answer (score 1):

redirects will not render the data from the view. You will need to render the request with the template and context

```
return redirect('/feeds/')
```

goes to

```
return render(request, 'dir/template.html', {'context':value})
```

Comment: Here feeds is not a view. It is another application in the same project. However the render method works i need to redirect, to avoid same operation performing in two views.